# Estoy intentando conectar mi flutter app con dart a una BDD Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, flutter, dart, async, connection

Llevo un par de días intentando usar esto para conectarme a SQL Server desde mi app de flutter:
https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket#readme
El error que me salta ahora es este:

```
'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>'
```

y no encuentro nada parecido por ningún sitio, alguien podría ayudarme? es mi primer post que hago, gracias.
Aquí es donde salta el error:

```
   /// formats and write a command to the socket
   Future<String> _SendCommand(String command)
   {
      // prepare buffer for response
      _receiveBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      
      _completer = new Completer();
      String cmd = command.length.toString() + "\r\n" + command;
      _socket.write(cmd);

      return _completer.future; // esta linea me lleva a la función Comprobarconexion() del main i salta error
   }
```

Codigo del main:

```
void main() async{
  runApp(MyApp());
  ComprobarConnexion();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainMenu(),
      theme: new ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'San Francisco',
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1),
      ),
    );
  }
 }
 ComprobarConnexion() async {
   var conn = new SqlConnection("SERVER=****;Database=***;Uid=****;Password=****",address: '****', port: ****);
  print(Text('Starting connection'),);
  try {
    await conn.open();
    print(Text('Connection OPEN!'),);
  }
  catch(e){
     print(e);
     print(Text('Connection Failed'),);
  }
  await conn.close();
  print(Text('Connection Closed'),);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución al problema, era un problema del documento descargado del git.

sqlConnection.dart

Dejo aquí el código modificado por si alguien en algún momento se encuentra con lo mismo, muchas gracias a todos.

```
library sql_server_socket;

import "dart:io";
import "dart:async";
import "dart:convert";

import "table.dart";

class SqlConnection
{
   Socket _socket;
   StringBuffer _receiveBuffer;
   Completer _completer;
   bool _connected;
   
   String _address;
   int _port;
   String _connectionString;
   
   SqlConnection(String connStr, {String address: "localhost", int port: 10980})
   {
      _address = address;
      _port = port;
      _connected = false;
      _connectionString = connStr;
   }
   
   /// tells if database is connected
   bool get connected => _connected;  
   
   /// connects to sql server database using the specified connection string
   Future<dynamic> open() async
   {
      try
      {
         this._socket = await Socket.connect(_address, _port);
         print("Connected to: ${_socket.remoteAddress.address}:${_socket.remotePort}");
      }
      catch(ex)
      {
         throw "can't connect to ${_address}:${_port} -- $ex";         
      }
       
      //Establish the onData, and onDone callbacks
      utf8.decoder.bind(_socket).listen(_receiveData, onError: _onError, onDone: _onDone);

      var connectCompleter = new Completer();
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "open", "text": _connectionString });
      
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
         var res = _parseResult(result);
         if(res is _OkResult)
         {
           _connected = true;
           connectCompleter.complete(true);
         }
         else if(res is _ErrorResult)
         {
           _connected = false;
           connectCompleter.completeError(res.error);         
         }
         else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
         _connected = false;
         connectCompleter.completeError(err);
      });         
       
      return connectCompleter.future;
   }
   
   /// disconnects from sql server
   Future<dynamic> close()
   {
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      Completer disconnectCompleter = new Completer();
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "close", "text": _connectionString });
      
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((risp)
      {
         var res = _parseResult(risp);
         
         if(res is _OkResult) 
         {
            _connected = false;
            disconnectCompleter.complete(true);
         }
         else if(res is _ErrorResult)
         {           
            disconnectCompleter.completeError(res.error);           
         }
         else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
        disconnectCompleter.completeError(err);    
      });               
      
      return disconnectCompleter.future;     
   }
   
   /// launch a query on the database, returning a table
   Future<Table> queryTable(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "table", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);

               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);          
          else if(res is _TableResult) 
          {
              var tres = res as _TableResult;              
              Table tab = new Table(this, tres.tableName, tres.rows, tres.columns);
              compl.complete(tab);
          }
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }

   Future<PostBackResponse> postBack(ChangeSet chg)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String params = json.encode(chg.toEncodable());
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "postback", "text": params });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);

               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);          
          else if(res is _PostBackResult) 
          {
              var tres = res as _PostBackResult; 
              PostBackResponse resp = new PostBackResponse();
              resp.idcolumn = tres.idcolumn;
              resp.identities = tres.identities;              
              compl.complete(resp);
          }
          else throw "invalid postback response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;           
   }
   
   /// launch a query on the database, returning all rows
   Future<dynamic> query(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "query", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);
               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);         
          else if(res is _QueryResult) compl.complete(res.rows);          
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }
   
   /// launch a query on the database, returning the first rows only
   Future<dynamic> querySingle(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "querysingle", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);
          
               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);          
          else if(res is _QueryResult)
          {   
              if(res.rows.length==0) compl.complete(null);
              else                   compl.complete(res.rows[0]);
          }
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }

   /// launch a query on the database, returning the value from the first column of the first row
   Future<dynamic> queryValue(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "queryvalue", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);

               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);         
          else if(res is _QueryResult)
          {
              if(res.rows.length==0) compl.complete(null);
              else                   compl.complete(res.rows[0]["value"]);
          }
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }

   /// executes a sql command, returning the number of rows affected
   Future<dynamic> execute(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "execute", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);
          
               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);          
          else if(res is _QueryResult)
          {
              if(res.rows.length==0) compl.complete(-1);
              else                   compl.complete(res.rows[0]["rowsAffected"]);
          }
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }

   /// formats and write a command to the socket
   Future<dynamic> _SendCommand(String command)
   {
      // prepare buffer for response
      _receiveBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      
      _completer = new Completer();
      String cmd = command.length.toString() + "\r\n" + command;
      _socket.write(cmd);

      return _completer.future;
   }

   void _onDone()
   {
       //print("onDone()");
       //_socket.destroy();
   }
   
   void _onError(error)
   {
       print("error occurred: $error");
   }
   
   /// receive data from socket and build a command string
   /// 
   /// client sends text-based commands with the format:
   /// size_of_command_string + "\r\n" + command_string
   void _receiveData(data)
   {      
      _receiveBuffer.write(data);
            
      String content = _receiveBuffer.toString();
      
      if(content.indexOf("\r\n")>0)
      {
         int x = content.indexOf("\r\n");
         int len = int.parse(content.substring(0,x)); // size of command string
         
         String cmd = content.substring(x+2);
         if(cmd.length==len)
         {           
           _completer.complete(cmd);           
         }              
      }
   }
   
   /// translates generic json result into a Result type
   dynamic _parseResult(String JSON)
   {
      Map result = json.decode(JSON);
      
           if(result["type"]=="ok")       return new _OkResult("ok");      
      else if(result["type"]=="error")    return new _ErrorResult(result["error"]);      
      else if(result["type"]=="query")    return new _QueryResult(result["rows"], result["columns"]);            
      else if(result["type"]=="table")    return new _TableResult(result["tablename"], result["rows"], result["columns"]);
      else if(result["type"]=="postback") return new _PostBackResult(result["idcolumn"], result["identities"]);
      else throw "unknown response";
   }         
}

class _ErrorResult
{
   String error;
   
   _ErrorResult(String error)
   {
      this.error = error;
   }
}

class _OkResult
{
   String ok;
   
   _OkResult(String ok)
   {
      this.ok = ok;
   }
}

class _QueryResult
{
   List rows;
   Map  columns;

   _QueryResult(List rows, Map columns)
   {
      this.rows = rows;
      this.columns = columns;
      
      // fix types 
      for(var fieldName in columns.keys)
      {
         TypeFixer.fixColumn(rows, fieldName, columns[fieldName]);
      }
   }  
}

class _TableResult
{
   String tableName;
   List rows;   
   List columns;
   
   _TableResult(String tableName, List rows, List columns)
   {
       this.tableName = tableName;
       this.rows = rows;
       this.columns = columns;       
   }
}

class _PostBackResult
{
   String idcolumn;
   List<int> identities;
   
   _PostBackResult(String idcolumn, List<int> identities)
   {
       this.idcolumn = idcolumn;
       this.identities = identities;
   }
}

/// translates a JSON encoded SQL type into a Dart type
class TypeFixer
{
   /// fix string data type coming from JSON into proper Dart data type
   static void fixColumn(List<dynamic> rows, String columnName, String columnType)
   {
       if(columnType=="datetime")
       {
         for(int t=0;t<rows.length;t++) 
         {
            if(rows[t][columnName]!=null) rows[t][columnName] = DateTime.parse(rows[t][columnName]);
         }   
       }
   }  
}
```